# how to decompress data in php and the data which use pako.deflate from js

Tags: php, compression, deflate, inflate, pako

I use `pako.deflate` to compress data in javascript, like this:

```
js file:

const params = [{id: 5, name: '张三', list: [{code: '10010', type: 'media'}]},{id: 6, name: '李四', list: [{code: '20010', type: 'site'}]}]

let binaryString = pako.deflate(JSON.stringify(params), { to: 'string' })

http.post({data: binaryString})...
```

and in the web server, I need to decompress that data using PHP.

This is what I do

```
php file:

$data = $params['data']; // got the right post data

$res = gzinflate(base64_decode($data));

echo $res; //echo false
```

but `$res` echo `false`

What am I missing?

Comment: check params data is actually what you expect. check base_64 is what you'd expect. You have three lines in one. Split them and it might help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are base 64 decoding at the server - do you actually base64 encode at the client at all prior to posting the data? There is no indication this is occurring in the code posted.

I suspect it is likely you are sending a deflated utf-8 string as your data, and then trying to base64 decode a string which contains a *far* greater range of characters.

Maybe look what characters `$params['data']` contains - if any of them are outside the base64 range (being `a-z`,`A-Z`, `0-9`, `+`, `/`, and possibly trailing `=`) then I think this would be the problem.

You could then try simply changing the line to:

```
$res = gzinflate($data);
```